# Do I need repeat biometrics when reapplying for a B1 visa?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

My B1 visa was rejected the first time I applied. When I re-apply, do I need to schedule biometrics to be done again, or is it only done once, the first time you apply?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your biometric validity is only as valid as long as your DS160. Since your application was rejected, it's no longer valid.

In either case, that's the very least of your problems. Unless there was an error on the part of the consulate in your first application processing or your circumstances changed, your re-application is likely to be denied again.

I would worry much more about being denied than about whether you'll be fingerprinted again.

Comment: A third possibility is that the OP submitted incomplete documentation of their circumstances, and is now ready to submit again.

Comment: He used the language "rejected" which does have ambiguity between denied and withdrawn.

Comment: but my circumstances are changed now, so why it will be denied again